# Scala type inference with generics and covariance, possible issue in scalac

Tags: generics, scala, inheritance

I have a short list of questions that I've found today.
I'm a scala novice, therefore my questions may be trivial.

Let's assume we have a class like this one:

```
abstract class A[+T] { def foo[S >: T](x: S): String }
```

And we should provide useful child class with some functionality.

1) My first attempt looks like this:

```
class B extends A[String] { def foo(x: String) = x }
```

but scalac compiler disagrees with message:

```
xxx@yyy:~$ scalac covariant.scala 
covariant.scala:3: error: class B needs to be abstract, since method foo in class A of type [S >: String](x: S)String is not defined
class B extends A[String] { def foo(x: String) = x }
      ^
```

First of all, why scalac didn't infer foo's generic type parameter, is it really a complex task?

2) Next try looks better and should be accepted, as I think:

```
class B extends A[String] { def foo[String](x: String) = x }
```

but now compiler made my eyes wide open:

```
covariant.scala:3: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String(in method foo)
 required: java.lang.String
class B extends A[String] { def foo[String](x: String) = x }
                                                         ^
```

It looks like an issue with that mismatch of String and java.lang.String. This is a second question: Is it really a bug?

3) Finally I've decided to switch String type to Date as parameter:

```
import java.util.Date
class B extends A[Date] { def foo[Date](x: Date) = x.toString }
```

It have been compiled without any warnings. So last question is: Why? What is the difference between my second and third snippets?

By the way, scalac version is `2.9.1.final`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Really, all your questions spring from the same misunderstanding.

You have the defined as "a class with a type parameter and a method foo that can act on any type <strike>*descended* from T</strike> from which T descends.

You supplied a class with a foo that can act on T but not <strike>necessarily</strike> on <strike>descendants (actually, since arguments are covariant, foo actually would work on descendants but the spec isn't tight enough to catch that)</strike> superclasses of T.

In the other two questions, you have accidentally reused the name of an existing type.  When you wrote foo[Date] or foo[String], you weren't referring, as you apparently thought, to java.lang.String or java.lang.Date but new types of the same name!  That's why you see a mismatch of String and java.lang.String -- they're two different types.

Try this instead:

```
abstract class A[+T] { def foo[S >: T](x: S): String }
class B extends A[String] { def foo[S >: String](x: S) = x.toString }
```

<strike>Yes, the `S >: String` is kind of pointless since String is final, but the spec cannot carve out every possible edge case.</strike>

**NOTE**  I'm something of a tyro too, so don't be shocked if my answer is wrong/misleading.  And remember: this advice is guaranteed worth twice what you paid for it or your money cheerfully refunded.

**TOLD YA** Big error: I reversed superclass and subclass.  Corrections made inline with <strike>strikeouts</strike>.

**AN EXAMPLE** The OP isn't clear why all this is necessary.  Consider the following function

```
def foo3(a : A[String]) = a.foo(3)
```

That's legal because 3 (as java.lang.Integer) is an example of an Object, which is an ancestor of A. If B.foo were defined as taking a String and nothing else, an instance of B could not be passed into foo3.

Comment: Pretty good, except `S >: T` means `S` must be a _super_ type of of `T`, not a descendant. So, for isntance, this call is valid: `new B.foo(new java.util.Date)`, as `S` is inferred to be `AnyRef`, a supertype of `String` (and `java.util.Date`).

Comment: D'oh!  That makes much more sense.  So it wasn't a gap in the spec -- or rather two gaps in the spec, there's a huge difference between a function that takes a supertype of T as an argment and one that that takes T, and of course, String being final doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't get one thing about refererring type in param of function foo. Can I pass concrete parameter into foo's declaration? Your code `def foo[S >: String](x: S) = x.toString` doesn't allow to interpret x as String.